# Apache Camel: detect if it is the last route in the chain

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the following scenario. I am working with chained routes  key_123 --> key_345 --> key_678. The onCompletion method
is being called after every route. Is it possible in onCompletion to detect if it is the last route in the chain? Since I want
to remove the correlation_id just at the end of the chain (in this case key_678 route) and not after every route.

**Code:**

```
    from("quartz://key_123?cron=0+0/10+*+*+*+?+*")
        .
        .
        .
    .to("activemq:topic:key_345");
    

    from("activemq:topic:key_345")
        .
        .
        .
    .to("direct:key_678");
    
    
    onCompletion().onCompleteOnly()
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            CamelContext context = exchange.getContext();
            Boolean isRunAllowed = context.isRunAllowed();
            ServiceStatus status = context.getStatus();
            //TODO: Check if it is the last route in the chain.
            MDC.remove("correlation_id");
        }
    });
```

Is it possible to detect the first and last route in the chain in Apache Camel?